# Como cambiar el texto "Es seguro" que sale cuando tu pagina tiene SSL

Tags: ssl

Tengo unas cuantas páginas con certificado SSL instalado y cuando entras desde Chrome en ellas sale el candado verde junto al texto "Es seguro".
Navegando por Internet he visto que algunas páginas como la de la Policía (https://www.policia.es/) en el lugar del "Es seguro" aparece "Dirección General de la Policía [ES]".
La pregunta es es posible hacer que en mis páginas deje de salir "Es seguro" para que salga otro texto, como ocurre en la página de la Policía.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Me parece que es para empresas, sociedades u organismos, pero siendo sincero no estoy seguro.

Answer (score 4):

Depende de cuánto estés dispuesto a pagar por el certificado de seguridad.

En sí lo que pasa es que hay distintos niveles de certificados SSL, y para ilustrarme usaré a [GoDaddy](https://mx.godaddy.com/web-security#secure):

> **SSL de validación de dominio Estándar**
>
> Perfecto para sitios web personales y blogs.

Un certificado simple, lo único que hace es encriptar el tráfico de datos entre el cliente (navegador del visitante) y el servidor. Con ello, obtienes el candado y el navegador aceptará el protocolo `https`.

> **SSL de validación de organización Deluxe**
>
> Ideal para los sitios web únicamente informativos: educación, organizaciones sin fines de lucro, etc.

Estos certificados sirven para darle más "tranquilidad" al visitante, ya que con estos se requiere una validación por parte de quien emite el certificado (para el caso, GoDaddy) de que el dueño del sitio es quien dice ser.

> **SSL de validación extendida Premium**
>
> Recomendado para las tiendas web. Presenta la barra de direcciones verde que buscan los compradores.

Estos certificados son más caros, pero exhiben el nombre de la entidad dueña del dominio, por lo tanto requieren que el dueño demuestre ser quien dice ser. Con éste se gana la "barra verde" y el nombre que quieres desplegar, que es a lo que tú quieres llegar.

### Conclusión

Lo que quieres no depende de programación, sino del certificado que instales en tu sitio. Esto es así porque en internet no puedes fiarte de nadie, así que si quieres hacer operaciones delicadas, deben existir más filtros que te impidan, por ejemplo, perder tu dinero.

Answer (score 2):

Se les llama certificados de validación extendida, aparece el nombre de la organización en verde en la barra de direcciones, ademas de que son certificados más seguros.

Puedes ver más info en los siguientes enlaces (no estoy promocionando estas marcas) que tienen  buena info

https://www.certsuperior.com/SecureSiteProEV.aspx 
https://www.digicert.com/es/certificados-ev-ssl.htm